# Как правильно подставить имена свойств объекта, если они сохранены в свойствах класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Привет.

Есть массив объектов

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [param] => vote_date
            [value] => 2014-09-30
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [param] => test
            [value] => no no no
        )

)
Обходим его
foreach($array as $item) {
     echo $item->param.' => '.$item->value.'<br>';
}
```

А теперь давайте представим, что дело происходит внутри класса, и имена свойств объектов массива установлены в свойствах класса

```
 public $settings;
    public $field_name = 'param';
    public $field_value = 'value';

    function __construct($array){
    $this->settings = new stdClass();
     Обходим массив
    //этот код вызывает ошибку
        foreach($array as $item) {
            $this->settings->$this->field_name = $this->field_value; 
        }

    }
```

Вопрос: как правильно подставить имена свойств объекта, если они сохранены в свойствах класса?

Comment: Почитайте про оператор $, это весьма пригодится, когда будете видеть конструкции вроде:  

    $$$$name

Или даже.  

    $$$$$$$$name

Нужно как-то так:  

    $this->$param_name

Comment: Не пробовал, но должно взлететь

    $this->settings->{$this->field_name}